# Error Search Guard not initialized (SG11) for indices:admin/exists

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am new to ELK stack and want to use authentication in it.For that I am going to use Search guard plugin in elasticsearch.
I have installed it with the help of below link:

https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard-docs

Then I was following all the steps given there but unfortunately got the below error while running sgadmin

```
An unexpected ElasticsearchSecurityException occured: Search Guard not 
initialized (SG11) for indices:admin/exists
```

And I tried to solve the error with help of various links:

https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard/issues/366

https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard-docs/blob/master/sgadmin.md

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/search-guard/kBwjU8JtTkk/5KShZiiwCQAJ

But no luck...
If anyone having any idea to solve the error please help me with it. 
Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard/issues/366 and https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard/issues/282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are using a node certificate with sgadmin, not an admin certificate. Or you configured a node certificate as admin certificate in elasticsearch.yml.

In short, sgadmin requires a separate TLS certificate, and this certificate must not be used as node certificate. Please check the following sections in your elasticsearch.yml:

```
searchguard.nodes_dn:
  - 'CN=node.other.com,OU=SSL,O=Test,L=Test,C=DE'
  - ...
```

and

```
searchguard.authcz.admin_dn:
  - CN=admin,OU=SSL,O=Test,L=Test,C=DE
  - ...
```

Make sure you use a separate certificate in searchguard.authcz.admin_dn. This certificate must not be listed in the searchguard.nodes_dn section.

When executing sgadmin, make sure you use the certificate configured in searchguard.authcz.admin_dn.

Comment: What is the difference between node certificate and admin certificate and where we can get it.I am little confused.Can you tell me just once. May be it will solve my issue.

Comment: An admin certificate is just a regular TLS certificate with elevated permissions. In order to grant a TLS certificate these admin permissions, you just need to configure it in elasticsearch.yml with the searchguard.authcz.admin_dn key. The types of certificates are explained here: http://docs.search-guard.com/latest/tls-in-production If you use the demo installer script, you can use the kirk TLS certificate for it.

Comment: After running sgadmin.bat I am getting error.If I am trying to run 
 sgadmin.bat -cert D:\Software\elasticsearch-5.5.2\config\kirk.jks  its showing like parsing failed.Can you please explain me how to run sgadmin?